# How to count len of strings in a list without built-in function?

Tags: python

How can I create a function `count_word` in order to get the result like this:

```
x = ['Hello', 'Bye']
print(count_word(x))
# Result must be [5, 3]
```

without using `len(x[index])` or any built-in function?

Comment: Create your own function(that will Iterate through the characters and increment the counter by one) and then do `list(map(your_funtion, x))` . or `[your_function(i) for i in x]`

Comment: Why can't you use `len` or any other built-in function?

Comment: Odds are its an assignment for university or similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String length without len function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992192/string-length-without-len-function)

Comment: @GinoMempin This does not answer the question, since here *no built-in functions are allowed* and the linked question only does not accept `len()`.

Comment: Define "built-in function".

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions

Comment: @colidyre There are answers in that duplicate that don’t use built-in functions, like using a for loop and just counting the iterations (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457074/2745495)) or using list methods (unless list methods also count as built-in, in which case answers here that use list.append are also not allowed). None of the current answers here differ from the answers in that duplicate, the only diff being the OP has to apply it to a list of strings instead of just a string.

Comment: @GinoMempin The linked answer uses 'print' ;) - but I have to agree that there are other interesting answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993450/2648551) -- my favorite! I agree that there are a lot of similarities (t)here. For me it is not enough to vote for a duplicate. But I could live with it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not allowed to use built-in functions, you have to iterate over each string in the list and over all characters of each word as well. Also you have to memorize the current length of each word and reset the counter if the next word is taken. This is done by re-assigning the counter value to 0 (`length = 0`) before the next inner iteration will be started:

```py
def count_word(x):
    result = []
    for word in x:
        length = 0
        for char in word:
            length += 1
        result.append(length)
    return result
```

Please note that this is probably the no-brainer par excellence. However, Python offers some interesting other approaches to solve this problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3992192/2648551) are some other interesting examples, which of course need to be adapted.

---

While this should answer your questions, I would like to add some notes about performance and why it is better to use built-in functions:

Generally spoken, built-in functions are doing the iteration under the hood for you or are even faster by e.g. [simply getting the array’s length from the CPython list head structure](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython) *(emphasis mine)*:

> **How are lists implemented in CPython?**
>
> CPython’s lists are really variable-length arrays, not Lisp-style linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of references to other objects, and **keeps a pointer to** this array and **the array’s length in a list head structure**.
>
> This makes indexing a list `a[i]` an operation whose cost is independent of the size of the list or the value of the index.
>
> When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is resized. Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of appending items repeatedly; when the array must be grown, some extra space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual resize.

*(Credits also to Ken Y-N, see [How does len(array) work under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42942135/2648551))*

Generally, it is better to use built-in functions whenever you can, because you seldom can beat the performance of the underlying implementation (e.g. for C-based Python installations):

```py
def count_word_2(x):
    return [len(word) for word in x]
```

You can see that if you time the two given functions:

```py
In [1]: from timeit import timeit

In [2]: statement = 'count_word(["Hello", "Bye"])'

In [3]: count_word_1 = """
   ...: def count_word(x):
   ...:     result = []
   ...:     for word in x:
   ...:         length = 0
   ...:         for char in word:
   ...:             length += 1
   ...:         result.append(length)
   ...:     return result
   ...: """

In [4]: count_word_2 = """
   ...: def count_word(x):
   ...:     return [len(word) for word in x]
   ...: """

In [5]: timeit(stmt=statement, setup=count_word_1, number=10000000)
Out[5]: 4.744415309000033

In [6]: timeit(stmt=statement, setup=count_word_2, number=10000000)
Out[6]: 2.7576589090022026
```

If also a little bit of *cheating* is allowed (using string dunder method `__len()__` instead of built-in function `len()`), you can get some performance back (credits to HeapOverflow):

```py
In [7]: count_word_3 = """
...: def count_word(x):
...:     return [word.__len__() for word in x]
...: """

In [8]: timeit(stmt=statement, setup=count_word_3, number=10000000)
Out[8]: 3.313732603997778
```

So a good rule of thumb is: Do whatever you can with built-in functions. They are more readable and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['Hello', 'Bye']
results = []
for single_string in x:
    string_length = 0
    for i in single_string: string_length += 1
    results.append(string_length)
print(results)
```

Comment: Oh no, you used the `print` built-in function!

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I imagine if this is for a uni/college assignment or quiz, then you'll be asked to submit the function definition only, and therefore you'll not use `print()` anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['Hello', 'Bye']
def count(x):
    i=0
    for j in x:i+=1
    return i
print(list(map(count, x)))
```

Comment: Here you're using built-in functions `list` and `map` for getting the wanted result. It is clear that OP doesn't want to use any built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using inline assignment (Python >= 3.8)

```
def count(word):
    c = 0
    return [[_ for _ in word if (c := c+1)], c][1]

words = ['Hello', 'How are you', 'Bye!']

>>> [count(w) for w in words]
[5, 11, 4]
```

Or even passing `c` as an input argument (defaulted to 0) could be used as an accumulated result from previous counts:

```
def count(word, c=0):
    return [[_ for _ in word if (c := c+1)], c][1]

ctot = [0]
[ctot.append(count(w, ctot[-1])) for w in words]  # sort of equivalent to built-in 'reduce'

>>> ctot  # or ctot[1:] to ignore the first zero
[0, 5, 16, 20]
```